# Where can I find the range interval partition tablespaces in the data dictionary?

Tags: oracle, partitioning, intervals

For a range interval partitioned table, you can specify multiple tablespaces like:

```
CREATE TABLE range_part_interval_table(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER)
PARTITION BY RANGE (col1)
INTERVAL (10) STORE IN (ts2, ts3, ts4)
(PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (100) TABLESPACE ts1);
```

But I can't find where the interval tablespaces are stored in the data dictionary (here, `ts2, ts3, ts4`). Is this information available somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the info you need:

```
SELECT table_owner, table_name, partition_name, tablespace_name 
FROM dba_tab_partitions 
WHERE table_name = <table_name>;
```

The following is the table description:

```
%> desc dba_tab_partitions

Name                           Null                             Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
------------------------------ -------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
TABLE_OWNER                                                     VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
TABLE_NAME                                                      VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
COMPOSITE                                                       VARCHAR2(3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
PARTITION_NAME                                                  VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SUBPARTITION_COUNT                                              NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
HIGH_VALUE                                                      LONG()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH                                               NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PARTITION_POSITION                                              NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
TABLESPACE_NAME                                                 VARCHAR2(30)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PCT_FREE                                                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PCT_USED                                                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
INI_TRANS                                                       NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
MAX_TRANS                                                       NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
INITIAL_EXTENT                                                  NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
NEXT_EXTENT                                                     NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
MIN_EXTENT                                                      NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
MAX_EXTENT                                                      NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
MAX_SIZE                                                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
PCT_INCREASE                                                    NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
FREELISTS                                                       NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
FREELIST_GROUPS                                                 NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
LOGGING                                                         VARCHAR2(7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
COMPRESSION                                                     VARCHAR2(8)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
COMPRESS_FOR                                                    VARCHAR2(18)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
NUM_ROWS                                                        NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
BLOCKS                                                          NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
EMPTY_BLOCKS                                                    NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
AVG_SPACE                                                       NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
CHAIN_CNT                                                       NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
AVG_ROW_LEN                                                     NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
SAMPLE_SIZE                                                     NUMBER                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
LAST_ANALYZED                                                   DATE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
BUFFER_POOL                                                     VARCHAR2(7)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
GLOBAL_STATS                                                    VARCHAR2(3)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
USER_STATS                                                      VARCHAR2(3)
```

Comment: That's the tablespaces of the predefined partitions, not the ones in the INTERVAL ... STORE IN (...) clause

Comment: dba_tab_partitions contains all partition tablespaces that exist, even the interval tablespaces specified in the "store in" clause.  I'm unable to test/verify this b/c I'm currently working with an older Oracle instance, but the info on the non-existent interval tablespace may be available in the all_tab_partitions table. You may try checking there for the tablespace names that aren't in existence yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your interval partitions don't exist until you have some data in them....

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE range_part_interval_table(col1 NUMBER, col2 NUMBER)
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (col1)
  3  INTERVAL (10) STORE IN (ts2, ts3, ts4)
  4  (PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (100) TABLESPACE ts1);

Table created.

SQL> SELECT table_owner, table_name, partition_name, tablespace_name
  2  FROM dba_tab_partitions
  3  WHERE table_name = 'RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE'
  4  /

TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME                     PARTITION_NAME TABLESPACE_NAME
----------- ------------------------------ -------------- ---------------
APC         RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      SYS_P55        TS1

SQL>
```

The empty table has only the defined partition.  But if we insert some data for different intervals....

```
SQL> insert into range_part_interval_table values (90, 8888)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into range_part_interval_table values (110, 8888)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into range_part_interval_table values (310, 8888)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> insert into range_part_interval_table values (120, 8888)
  2  /

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT table_owner, table_name, partition_name, tablespace_name
  2  FROM dba_tab_partitions
  3  WHERE table_name = 'RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE'
  4  /

TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME                     PARTITION_NAME TABLESPACE_NAME
----------- ------------------------------ -------------- ---------------
APC         RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      SYS_P58        TS2
APC         RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      SYS_P55        TS1
APC         RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      SYS_P56        TS4
APC         RANGE_PART_INTERVAL_TABLE      SYS_P57        TS3

SQL>
```

Comment: But I ideally need the information on the STORE IN (ts2, ts3, ts4) irregardless of the number of partitions that have actually been created from it...

Answer (score 0):

check sys.insert_tsn_list$